# AWS CDK + SAM for Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I'm trying to locally invoke my aws lambda golang application and keep getting `{"errorMessage":"fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory","errorType":"PathError"}`

I'm using [this](https://github.com/cowcoa/aws-cdk-go-examples/tree/master/lambda/single_function) Repo as a guide

Steps:

1. `cdk init app --language go`
2. create `/config` & `/function` directories
3. copy `/config/config.go` & `/function/main.go`
4. `go mod tidy` (`go mod init` if needed)
5. Add cdk lambda definition (see below)
6. `cdk synth`
7. `sam local invoke SingleFunction --no-event -t ./cdk.out/${stackname}.template.json --debug`

```
awslambda.NewFunction(stack, jsii.String(config.FuncionName), &awslambda.FunctionProps{
        FunctionName: jsii.String(*stack.StackName() + "-" + config.FuncionName),
        Runtime:      awslambda.Runtime_GO_1_X(),
        MemorySize:   jsii.Number(config.MemorySize),
        Timeout:      awscdk.Duration_Seconds(jsii.Number(config.MaxDuration)),
        Code:         awslambda.AssetCode_FromAsset(jsii.String(config.CodePath), nil),
        Handler:      jsii.String(config.Handler),
    })
```

Comment: Does the stack deploy without error?  Also, make sure `./cdk.out/${stackname}.template.json` resolves to the template location.

Comment: @fedonev I have not tried deploying it, as I'm just trying locally, but even if I just do `go run main.go` I get the same error. So I'm pretty sure it's something with the GOROOT setup and not specific to aws cdk

Comment: I got it to work, the issue was the handler was not the name of the go executable, but instead the name of the main function